# Cannot send data read from csv file (comma separated) to javascript using django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Hello I haven't been able to use data from file comma separated in javascript.
So far i've been trying to read it in python and send it through django to javascript in json format but nothing seems to work.

In the File views.py I have:

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import json

def home2view(request):

        f= open('filess.csv','r' )

        reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ( "name","lat","lng") )
        out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )
        return render(request,'index3test.html', {"out":out})
```

If I print out, I get this:

```
[{"name": "EU", "lng": "149.0321159", "lat": "-23.2869226"}, 
{"name": "ES", "lng": "120.2920532", "lat": "-20.621217"}]
```

Why cant I send it to javascript? this is not even executing (I use pythonanywhere) and I only know this:

There was an error loading your PythonAnywhere-hosted site. There may be a bug in your code.

Error code: Unhandled Exception

I checked the error log but there is nothing there.

I think it has to do with how i'm sending the data.

Comment: We don't know why you can't send it to javascript. What did you try? What error did you get? What does "this is not even executing" mean?

Comment: `json.dumps()` returns a string, so the value of `out` is just a plain string that happens to look a lot like json.  If you want to to turn it into a real json object inside your javascript code, you'll have to parse it.

Comment: I don't know where is the error, because I just click reload to build the project and it shows this:
 There was an error loading your PythonAnywhere-hosted site. There may be a bug in your code.

Error code: Unhandled Exception

Comment: When is the error happening?  When you try to load the page in your browser?  If so, there should be some kind of error message in the web server error log.

Comment: The last error I have on server log is: 2017-05-08 18:51:38 Not Found: /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
But I have been trying to run it two minutes ago, I comment those lines and the rest of the project works perfect. I am not even receiving the variable in javascript yet.
The error is when I reload the project and load the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )
```

json.dumps creates a string so you're sending a string through to the template.  You need to send an array (or some other set) of the items you want to pass through

Comment: But how do I convert it? Or should I read the file differently?

Comment: Django templates know how to work with python objects.  So you can make `out` a regular python list by saying `out = [ row for row in reader ]`, then in your template you can do `{% for row in out %} <p>{{row.name}}, {{row.lng}}, {{row.lat}}</p> {% endfor %}`

Comment: IT is still not working:  
def home2view(request):

        f= open('mines.csv','r' )

        reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ( 'name','lat','lng') )
        out = [ row for row in reader ]


        return render(request,'index3test.html', {'out':out})

Comment: Have you added the proposed template code from John Gordon to your template?

Comment: I haven't called it from the template, because I already have python problems to build the project. Anybody could please put here an example of a code that works in python? just any simple example of sending a variable. I have tried many. Thanks in advance.